Deployment of Static Site Generation (SSG) in next.js 14 version
I need to build a Next.js app where I have Static Site Generation (SSG) pages. This means that I want to generate static pages at build time. I need to get information for my static pages from a server, but the Next.js server itself is down during the build process, so I can't get the information.
How can I fix this in the App Router?
What are the best practices for handling this situation?
Sorry if this is a duplicate, but please provide some info to read about it.
Thank you!
